# How to read excel column that has custom format using pandas?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

Excel data:
[image: Excel Data]

Excel cell format:
[image: Excel cell format]

Pandas output:
[image: Pandas output]

Pandas read code:

`df = pandas.read_excel(printsheet, sheet_name="Condition", skiprows=1, keep_default_na=False)`

I need pandas to output the data as in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether you want that to be adaptive to the formatting in the Excel file or if you already know the formatting and simply want to convert it.

As a general rule, you could use [xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for older xls files or [xlrd github](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd) (or maybe [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) to read 2010+ formats (xlsx) formats from your excel workbook.  These libraries can extract the formatting with methods such as:

```
wkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(printsheet, formatting_info=True)  
xf_index = wkbook.sheet_by_index(0).cell_xf_index(5,7)  
xf = wkbook.xf_list[xf_index]  
fmt = wkbook.format_map[xf.format_key]  
print(fmt.format_str, fmt.type)
```

so that you can reconstruct it where needed with methods such as:

```
xlrd.xldate_as_datetime(xlT, 0)
```

But if you already know the format, you could convert the excel data into the format you want or data types you want.  For example, you could simply create a function to convert the excel time format to your desired format or to a datetime type - whichever makes the most sense for you. Like:

```
def excelTimeToTuple(xlT):
    h = xlT * 24 % 24
    m = h * 60 % 60
    s = m * 60 % 60
    return (
        int(h),
        int(m),
        int(s),
    )
```

Even if your case is that you need to read the formats and then adapt, you will need some type casting functions to make the conversions that you want afaik. *There could be some format writing functions in xlrd, OpenPyXL or xlwriter as well.*